# How can we calculate the standard deviation of multiple values with different uncertainties each?

Tags: standard-deviation, error, uncertainty

For example, if I have a set of readings, like:

```
13.4 +/- 0.5
14.5 +/- 0.7
12.8 +/- 0.6
13.9 +/- 0.4
14.8 +/- 0.5
```

How do I calculate the standard deviation of these values? Would the standard deviation stay the same as it would for the base values only? If yes, why?

Comment: What do those $\pm$ figures represent, exactly?

Comment: The uncertainty. +/- is ±

Comment: Let me try again. What, exactly, does `+/- 0.5` represent  in `13.4 +/- 0.5`

Comment: Oh. Apologies for the misinterpretation. The +/- 0.5 represents that the actual value could be in the range of (13.4 - 0.5) to (13.4 + 0.5), which represents the uncertainty.

Comment: Is the actual value equally likely to be anywhere in that range or more likely to be near the middle? Is it possible for it to be outside those limits?

Comment: I think it should mean that the value can lie between the limits, with equal probability for all the possible values. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How would I know? They're your readings. Different equipment can have different specifications.

Comment: Yes, any value is possible between the range.

Comment: "Any value is possible in the range" doesn't address whether any values are possible outside it. You're confident about the equally likely part?

Comment: Pretty confident.

Comment: Are these all measurements made on the same object, but by different devices? Are you interested in the standard deviation so that you can have an error estimate for the average of these 5 sets of readings? Or is there some other reason why you want the standard deviation?

Comment: Each of these readings are obtained from averaging 5 other readings, with the same uncertainty, which is of the measurement device. The uncertainties shown in the values above are actually the standard deviation of those 5 values. Now, I need to standard deviation of these values to find the error in the uncertainty of the final average value.